# Inclusive/Exclusive Pronouns and Agreement Mismatch

Tags: morphology, agreement, clusivity

The following data (taken from Adger's Core Syntax) show that certain forms cause mismatching agreement. The dual, in Hopi, triggers both singular and plural agreement.

```
Puma  ta?taq-t wari 
Those man-PL   ran-SG
"Those two men ran"
```

In Classical Greek, neuter plural nouns trigger singular agreement on a verb, but plural agreement on an adjective.

```
Kala         en         ta  sphagia
Good-NEUT.PL be-PAST.SG the sacrifice-NEUT.PL
"The sacrifices were good
```

Does anyone know whether inclusive and exclusive pronouns also trigger mismatch agreement? Data would be much appreciated.

Comment: @sumelic In the context of the data provided, it is not the number of the noun that triggers number agreement, but the gender of the noun that does so. It doesn't matter whether the noun is singular or plural.

Comment: At least in Australian languages it seems there will be correct verbal agreement in singular in sg.excl., and correct in inclusive, too (dual/paucal/plural depending on the actual number of the DP and on the plural vs augmented system).

Comment: @sumelic No clue. I know absolutely nil about Classical Greek. The data above are from Core Syntax.